# How to determine Local Port for a socket established in VB6

Tags: sockets, vb6, winsock

In a VB6 Application, I am looking for a way to determine the Local Port for the duplex socket.

I have the remote Ip and Port, but I need to know an print out the local port as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just query the Winsock control's **LocalPort** property.

The LocalPort property is used both to set the send/listen port and to retrieve it once the connection has been established.  Even if you specify port 0, in which case the control will select a random port, after a connection is established, this property will contain that port number.

Comment: Assuming TCP, it is usually a bad idea not to set LocalPort to 0 before connecting.  Otherwise after disconnecting you won't be able to reconnect until ~ 4 minutes elapse.  Search on "TIME-WAIT" for more details.

Comment: Yes, I have run into that 4 minute issue myself.  2*ML where ML is set in the registry.  The ML value is 4 minutes by default, but can be lowered to 15 seconds.  I do not believe you can set it to a value of less than 15 seconds, giving a reconnect wait of 30 seconds min.  But the advice about the LocalPort to 0 avoids that until you run out of the 5000 sockets per user limit that windows has.